# jitsi/jigasi: call in fails to be established - unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: webrtc, sip, jitsi-meet

I've set up a jitsi-meet server with Hetzner App (Ubuntu 20.04) and a one-click-app. This works fine. I can join the meeting and talk.

Now I would like to add jigasi so that I can join the meeting by calling a phone number. So I install the package with `apt jigasi` and follow the edit instructions in https://github.com/jitsi/jigasi#jigasi point 4.

After I restarted the service I see the incoming call in the log file, but it is missing a certificate:
(For the sake of anonymity/privacy, I replaced my domain with example.com in the log below)

```
2023-09-09 13:21:19.488 INFO: [76] SipGateway$SipCallListener.incomingCallReceived#216: [ctx=1694265679473649756802] Incoming call received...
2023-09-09 13:21:20.503 INFO: [78] SipGatewaySession$WaitForJvbRoomNameThread.run#1600: [ctx=1694265679473649756802]Using default JVB room name property room1@conference.meet.example.com
2023-09-09 13:21:20.525 INFO: [78] JvbConference.start#454: [ctx=1694265679473649756802] Starting JVB conference room: room1@conference.meet.example.com
2023-09-09 13:21:20.546 INFO: [78] JvbConference.setXmppProvider#590: [ctx=1694265679473649756802] Using ProtocolProviderServiceJabberImpl(Jabber:2184b5c6@meet.example.com/2184b5c6)
2023-09-09 13:21:20.615 SEVERE: [83] net.java.sip.communicator.impl.protocol.jabber.ProtocolProviderServiceJabberImpl.connectAndLogin: Failed to connect to XMPP service for:ProtocolProviderServiceJabberImpl(Jabber:2184b5c6@meet.example.com/2184b5c6)
org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$SmackWrappedException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.setCurrentConnectionExceptionAndNotify(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:687)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.notifyConnectionError(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:987)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.access$4100(XMPPTCPConnection.java:131)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1167)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.access$700(XMPPTCPConnection.java:916)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader$1.run(XMPPTCPConnection.java:939)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:360)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:303)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:298)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:654)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:183)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1511)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1421)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:456)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:427)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.proceedTLSReceived(XMPPTCPConnection.java:733)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.access$1400(XMPPTCPConnection.java:131)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:990)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:222)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:638)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:146)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:127)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
    ... 23 more
2023-09-09 13:21:20.629 WARNING: [86] org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.callConnectionClosedOnErrorListener: Connection XMPPTCPConnection[not-authenticated] (1) closed with error
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:360)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:303)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:298)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:654)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:183)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1511)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1421)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:456)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:427)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.proceedTLSReceived(XMPPTCPConnection.java:733)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.access$1400(XMPPTCPConnection.java:131)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:990)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.access$700(XMPPTCPConnection.java:916)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader$1.run(XMPPTCPConnection.java:939)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:222)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:638)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:146)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:127)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
    ... 23 more
2023-09-09 13:21:20.634 SEVERE: [83] JvbConference.registrationStateChanged#656: [ctx=1694265679473649756802] XMPP Connection failed. RegistrationStateChangeEvent[ oldState=Registering; newState=RegistrationState=Connection Failed; userRequest=false; reasonCode=6; reason=javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target]
```

If you need a look at some of the configuration files, feel free to request them because I'm not sure which of all of these to post.

Where is my mistake?